# Manipulate(exclude lines) a specific column of a .csv file, using UNIX/Linux

Tags: regex, linux, csv, unix, data-manipulation

I want to access and manipulate the fourth column of a csv file.In particular I want to exclude the lines that don't meet a specific requirement ( exclude the lines that do not have 3 character country code).

My data set:

```
Luxembourg,LUX,2017,9294689.12
Aruba,ABW,2017,927865.82
Nepal,NPL,2017,9028196.37
Bangladesh,BGD,2017,88057460.51
Costa Rica,CRI,2017,8695008.05
Chile,CHL,2017,84603249.72
Cook Islands,COK,2017,82045.41
World,OWIDWRL,1755,9361520
India,INDIA,1763,0
Asia and Pacific (other),,2017,5071156099
World,OWID_WRL,1752,9354192
Middle East,,1751,0
International transport,,1751,0
India,IND,1751,0
Europe (other),,1751,0
China,CHN,1751,0
Asia and Pacific (other),,1751,0
Americas (other),,1751,0
Africa,,1751,0
```

Thanks in advance.

I have already sorted my data file by year, 
but I don't know how to access the 4th column and use awk or sed.

Expected Data set:

```
Luxembourg,LUX,2017,9294689.12
Aruba,ABW,2017,927865.82
Nepal,NPL,2017,9028196.37
Bangladesh,BGD,2017,88057460.51
Costa Rica,CRI,2017,8695008.05
Chile,CHL,2017,84603249.72
Cook Islands,COK,2017,82045.41
```

Comment: Is it also required for the country code to be the 2nd item in the list, or can it appear anywhere in the line?

Comment: Could you please do mention your sample expected output? Along with what should be the logic of removing the last column in your post please.

Comment: The Country_Code is the Second column of the .csv file.I need the code in the second column, it makes more sense to keep the same structure.

Comment: Output set:                                                               Luxembourg,LUX,2017,9294689.12
Aruba,ABW,2017,927865.82
Nepal,NPL,2017,9028196.37
Bangladesh,BGD,2017,88057460.51
Costa Rica,CRI,2017,8695008.05
Chile,CHL,2017,84603249.72
Cook Islands,COK,2017,82045.41

Comment: @JohnTipotas, But question remains the same, what is the logic of removing 4th column,what are the conditions kindly do mention them as well and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, could you please try following. Where code looks if 2nd field of any line is NOT having exact 3 characters in it then DO NOT print that line.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $2~/^[a-zA-Z]{3}$/' Input_file
```

In case you have OLD `awk` where range `{3}` doesn't work the try.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $2~/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$/' Input_file
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                  ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                 ##Starting BEGIN section from here. Which will be executed before Input_file is being read
  FS=","               ##Setting field separator as comma here.
}                      ##Closing BEGIN section here.
$2~/^[a-zA-Z]{3}$/     ##Checking condition if 2nd field is starting with alphabets 3 occurrence of it and ending with it too.
                       ##Since awk works on method of condition then action; so if condition is TRUE then perform certain action.
                       ##In this case no action given so  by default print of line will happen.
' Input_file           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Yes you got it right,sorry for not been more specific.I wanted my output data set to have all the correct format in each column so I can work on it( I wanted the 2nd column to have exactly 3 characters/country_code). Moreover your suggestion works perfectly.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnTipotas, Yes this should work for you, code is looking for 3 characters only, let me add validations of characters too.

Comment: @JohnTipotas, Please check my EDIT and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please do mention the reason for down vote here?

Answer (score 1):

The below would output only lines with a 3 letter value in the second field:

```
awk --re-interval -F, 'tolower($2) ~ /^[a-z]{3}$/' country.txt
```

Checking the length is also possible, but this ensures only 3 letters are provided.

`--re-internval` allows you to use itnernval expressions in RE's as braces are reserved characters in awk.

`-F,` tells awk the input delimiter is comma.

`print` is the default action in awk, so `tolower($2) ~ /^[a-z]{3}$/` is a shorthand way of saying `tolower($2) ~ /^[a-z]{3}$/ {print}`

The `tolower($2)` is lowercasing the value of the second field, and `~` is the regex comparison operator, which we use to check for the beginning of the string `^`, then `[a-z]` repeated `{3}` times and the end of the string `$`.

Comment: `--re-interval` is way too old version of awk, you don't need it new ones IMHO.